# How to inspect the javascript functions and its arguments

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm very new to JS and I have been playing around with Jasmine.

In Jasmine, I can see a method called `spyOn`, which does inspect/spy the functions.

How does this works in js? Coming from Java background is it a proxy? How to write one?

Comment: Calling `.toString` on function returns it's body. `func.length` holds number of function parameters.

Comment: Oops...misunderstood your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the precise implementation [on GitHub](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/SpyRegistry.js), but here is a simplified explanation:

```
function mySpy(obj, methodName) {
    // remember the original method
    var originalMethod = obj[methodName];

    // ... then replace it with a method that ...
    obj[methodName] = function () {

        // ... does whatever additional thing it wants to do ...
        console.log(methodName + " called, first argument: " + arguments[0]);

        // ... and then calls the original method with the same arguments,
        // and returns the result.
        return originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
var o = {
    inc: function (x) { return x + 1; }
};
mySpy(o, "inc");
console.log(o.inc(13));
```

This will output

```
inc called, first argument: 13
14
```

Three important things for you to know, coming from a Java background, are

1. In JavaScript, it is not a problem to change an object's methods after the fact, dynamically. Calling `someObj.someMethod = someOtherFunction` is perfectly valid. (To be 100% precise, you may not actually be *overwriting* the original method, because it may be somewhere up the prototype chain, instead of on the object itself. That's an advanced topic though, and not very important here. Also, Java's distinction beween methods and class members doesn't apply to JavaScript.)
2. The special "variable" `arguments` inside a function contains whatever arguments the function was called with. In Java terms, imagine that `someMethod(Foo x1, Bar x2)` always has an implicit second signature of the type `someMethod(Object... arguments)`, meaning you could always use `x1` and `arguments[0]` interchangeably.
3. `obj.someName` and `obj["someName"]` are entirely equivalent in JavaScript. Because of this, you can easily access/change an object's properties using the property name as a string, something that in Java you would have to use reflection for.